# How to make a Text box only accept whole numbers? VB

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a Battle Simulation and I need to make it so that text boxes only display and accept whole numbers. i.e 1, 5, 268. I want is so that and decimals will be rounded to the nearest whole number. I may just be acting silly but I cant think of a solution that will run, here is what I have got so far:

```
    If AttackerMP.Text = Decimal Then
        AttackerMP.Text = Integer
    End If
```

Comment: Maybe a MaskedTextBox will help you?

Comment: What's wrong with the dedicated [**`NumericUpDown`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Validating` event, `Decimal.TryParse` and [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Private Sub AttackerMP_Validating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AttackerMP.Validating
    Dim d As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(AttackerMP.Text, d) Then
        Dim roundedInt = CInt(Math.Round(d))
        AttackerMP.Text = roundedInt.ToString()
    Else
        AttackerMP.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I did a while back that only allows numbers

```
Public Function NumericOnly(ByVal eChar As Char) As Boolean
    Dim chkStr As String = "0123456789"
    If chkStr.IndexOf(eChar) > -1 OrElse eChar = vbBack Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

You can place this in a module so that you have access to it throughout your solution. Then for any textbox that you want this type of functionality in, you just put the following into its KeyPress Event.

```
e.Handled = NumericOnly(e.KeyChar)
```

But keep in mind, there's always the numeric up/down control that already does this for you. You can even limit a min/max amounts easily with it.

Comment: Using `IndexOf()` for this purpose isn't very efficient. Did you know that there's a function called [**`Char.IsNumber()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: He wanted to allow doubles but round to the next integer

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just took it to mean that is someone typed a decimal to round it so I did this to suggest, why even let them do it. Force only whole numbers.

Comment: @CharlesMay maybe because it's a feature. I dont know ops requirements. The user copy pasts something and the textbox rounds

Answer (score 0):

How I made textbox only accept numbers and backspace in my project:

```
Private Sub Timeout_TextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Timeout_TextBox.KeyPress
    'Allow Numbers only and Backspace
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
        If Not Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a String = to a Data Type. A .Text property will always be a string. You can get the datatype of a literal (12.3) or a variable with the built in .net function .GetType.

You cannot assign a datatype (Integer) to a string with an equals sign. You would use CInt(AttackerMP.Text) or Integer.TryParse (see Tim's answer) or any of several other conversion/cast functions.

Although Tim's answer is the way to go. I am giving you a bit of code to play around with. It allows you to see what numbers are what type. See if you get the results you expect. Change the 12.3 to other numbers and see what happens.

```
Private Sub TestTypes()
        'This will return a string
        Dim t As Type = TextBox1.Text.GetType()
        MessageBox.Show(t.ToString)
        Dim t1 As Type = 12.3.GetType()
        If t1.Equals(GetType(Decimal)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("It is a decimal")
        ElseIf t1.Equals(GetType(Integer)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("It is an Integer")
        ElseIf t1.Equals(GetType(Single)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("It is a Single")
        ElseIf t1.Equals(GetType(Double)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("It is a Double")
        End If
    End Sub
```